# Calculated percentage from total values with segmentation analysis

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two columns: `nameplant` and `plantproduct`. Different `plantproduct`s belong to a same `nameplant`. I need to calculate the percentage from each `plantproduct` from the total amount of `plantproduct`s that belong to that plant.

Example:

```
Clapla clapro cantid        %
cyala  11002      10     66.6
cyala  11003       5     33.3
cyalb  12001      20     80.0
cyalb  12002       5     20.0
```

I have this subqueries, but it doesn't work:

```
SqlCommand cmddata = new SqlCommand("SELECT clapla, clapro, (SUM(cantid)/'" + GVar.diastot + "')/totsumcan FROM (SELECT clapla, SUM(sumcantid) AS totsumcan FROM (" +
                 " SELECT clapro, clapla, (SUM(cantid)/'" + GVar.diastot + "') AS sumcantid FROM datcpc WHERE fechab >= '" + GVar.xxini + "' AND fechab <= '" + GVar.xxfin + "' AND  clacen = '" + GVar.refi + "' AND tipflu = 'C' GROUP BY Clapro, clapla) AS inner_query) FROM datcpc GROUP BY clapla ) GROUP BY clapla,clapro ; ", adtabase);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that @t table in my solution example is already pre aggregated result of data extraction from DATCPC table. I only demonstrate how to calculate percentage.

```
-- SAMPLE DATA PREPARATION
declare @t as table ( 
     Clapla varchar(10)
    ,clapro varchar(10)
    ,cantid int
);

insert into @t values ('cyala','11002',10),('cyala','11003',5),('cyalb','12001',20),('cyalb','12002',5);
```

And my solution for your problem.

```
-- SOLUTION EXAMPLE
select Clapla,clapro,cantid,cast(cantid*100.0/SUM(cantid) over(partition by Clapla) as numeric(4,1)) pct from @t;
```

Update. The solution for SQL Server 2008.

```
-- SOLUTION EXAMPLE version 2008
with agg as ( 
    select Clapla,SUM(cantid) as Total 
    from @t 
    group by Clapla )
select t1.Clapla,t1.clapro,t1.cantid,cast(t1.cantid*100.0/agg.Total as numeric(4,1)) pct 
    from @t t1 join agg on t1.Clapla = agg.Clapla;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, excuse me but, do you know the syntaxis for the over partition command for sql server 2008? because when i run the query there is a problem of syntaxis please